# How do you calculate output voltage noise for reactive circuits?

Tags: circuit-design, noise, transfer-function, math, bandwidth

For circuits without any reactive elements, like voltage dividers for example, it's a relatively straightforward process to find what the output noise will be due to any present resistors. First, I swap any inputs out for ground, then I place a voltage source of magnitude \$\sqrt{4k_BTR_i\Delta f}\$ in series with each resistor \$R_i\$, where \$\Delta f\$ is my target bandwidth (being enforced by using a filter later on). After that, I solve for what the output voltage would be given all these sources, it coming out to be a linear combination of the various sources. The output voltage noise, then, is the root of the sum of the squares of each of the coefficient-voltage products present in the aforementioned linear combination. This procedure is easy to follow, but when reactive components are thrown in, things become muddled for me.

Specifically, I'm working to determine the output noise produced by a slightly modified non-inverting integrator circuit. With the inputs grounded for the purpose of noise analysis and the voltage noise sources added in, here is the overall circuit diagram:

|  |
| --- |
| [image: Non-inverting Integrator, noise sources present] |

... where node \$y\$ is the output (note that I've omitted the current noise contribution by the op-amp to keep things simpler).

I solve for \$y\$ using Laplace Transforms:
$$Y=T^Y_{V_{n0}}(s) V_{n0}+T^Y_{V_{n1}}(s) V_{n1}+T^Y_{V_{n2}}(s) V_{n2}$$
... where, for example, \$T^Y_{V_{n2}}(s)=\frac{1}{1+R_2C_4s}\$.

Using pages 2-4 of [this PDF](https://my.ece.msstate.edu/faculty/winton/CDNuE/SoftCopy/ch20.pdf), I see that its possible to calculate the magnitude of a resistive voltage source via these equations:

|  |
| --- |
| \$e_n^2=4k_BTR\Delta f \text{ where } \Delta f = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }G(f)df\$ |

... where \$G(f)\$ is stated ambiguously as "the (frequency dependent) power gain \$= v_{out}^2/v_{in}^2\$." Following its place in the PDF, the author uses the equation in an example to calculate the *output* voltage noise produced by the resistor in an RC circuit.

My question is this: if you use the square of the magnitude of a transfer function between a resistive noise source and another node (say the output)(i.e. \$G(f)=\left\|T^Y_{V_{n1}}(2\pi fj)\right\|^2\$), will the above equations give you the noise contribution provided by said source **at that node?** Or will it just give the magnitude of the voltage source 'component' seen in the circuit diagrams above?

Also, given that the op-amp is not a purely resistive noise source, could I use the equation for bandwidth up there (with \$G(f)=\left\|T^Y_{V_{n0}}(2\pi fj)\right\|^2\$) and then integrate the op-amp's input-referred noise spectral density over said bandwidth to get the noise caused by the op-amp as seen at the output?

If these aren't the case, how would I go about getting each of the output noise contributions? I'd appreciate it if answerers refrain from using Thevenin Theorem or anthropomorphic terms like 'impedance seen by X source,' as they just serve to further confuse things. A systematic, mathematical approach to solving this, *without the use of any arcane shortcuts*, would be ideal.